# Why does Blender not load a textured PLY's texture?

Tags: uv, import

I imported a `.ply` file and its texture as explained in the video [Importing meshes with separate textures in Blender 2.80](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=stz9pL_pq9I), for my Blender 2.93.

For some meshes it works well, but for another one that I textured in [Meshlab](http://www.meshlab.org/), the texture is not showing up; the mesh is shaded in its base colour only:

[image: missing texture in Blender 2.93]

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Blender is picky with loading **UV Maps** from `.ply` files. It seems that as of writing:

- Blender **cannot import per-Wedge UV** coordinates
- Blender **can import per-Vertex UV** coordinates

  - The names of the UV coordinates in the PLY header must be called `s` and `t`
  - They must not be called `texture_u` and `texture_v`, like Meshlab exports them.

    - In such case, simply edit the `.ply` file in a text editor, replacing `texture_u` -> `s`, and `texture_v` -> `t`.

If you provide a format that Blender cannot import, it will silently continue, skipping to import the UV Map.

### How to check if your UV map got imported correctly

Directly after your PLY import, In the **Properties** panel, **Object Data Properties** tab, check the **UV Maps** section. It should show 1 UV map, like this:

[image]

It should not be empty, like this:

[image]

### Example PLY headers

The header of a PLY file is plain text, so you can read it with a text editor. It will tell which form of UV map is present.

For a per-vertex UV one, with `s`/`t` coordinates, that **Blender can read**:

```
element vertex 200085
property float x
property float y
property float z
property float s
property float t
element face 66695
property list uchar int vertex_indices
end_header
```

For a per-vertex UV one, with `texture_u`/`texture_v` coordinates, that **Blender cannot read**:

```
element vertex 200085
property float x
property float y
property float z
property float texture_u
property float texture_v
element face 66695
property list uchar int vertex_indices
end_header
```

For a per-wedge UV one, that **Blender cannot read**:

```
element vertex 33793
property float x
property float y
property float z
element face 66695
property list uchar int vertex_indices
property list uchar float texcoord
end_header
```