# PLY + Png texture in blender

Tags: texturing, materials, uv-image-editor

I've been looking for a way to import a 3D file in PLY format into Blender, which has a PNG texture file.

I can't match my texture on my PLY.

[image: Blender ply + png]

When I import the same files in meshlab for example, the png is directly positioned well...

[image: MESHLAB PLY+PNG]

Here is what my texture file looks like generated by my dental scanner:

[image: texture file]

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is a link with the files: https://file.io/GzyTQww0DZHs

Comment: This doesn't look like a UV map, have you tried checking if the color isn't stored on the vertices as a color attribute ?

Comment: Blender doesn't see the UV of your PLY. When I export PLY from Meshlab as **OBJ** .. [UV map is seen by Blender](https://imgur.com/FMuFBdD).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Blender not load a textured PLY's texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/240331/why-does-blender-not-load-a-textured-plys-texture)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, thanks vklidu... Why OBJ and not PLY, that's the question :D

Comment: The first image clearly shows a mesh with the texture in Blender. This means it is not a duplicate of the one explaining how Blender does not load some UV coordinate format supported by PLY format.  If the mesh had no UV map, no texture would be displayed. In this case the texture is clearly on the object, only incorrectly, so this means UV map is there, it's only loaded incorrectly. I am sure this has a really good chance of being figured out, only if the blend file with the texture was shared...